# T-SQL query help - Join on based on IF/ELSE

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements, sap-erp

I am trying to find the retail price for articles in SAP using SQL but the nature of the Articles means that the current price can either be put against a parent or the child. The only way to tell which field I need to join on is if a certain field has a value in it or not.

I have 2 separate queries but I really need both the results in 1 result set somehow.

The MATNR is the article number & the M.PMATN is the parents article number. If the M.PMATN field is blank then I want to join like query #1 on M.MATNR = A.MATNR but if the M.PMATN is not blank then I want to use the value in that field as the join like M.PMATN = A.MATNR

Query #1- no parent article number exists so using article number = article number to get the price from the article itself:

```
SELECT A.MANDT, A.VKORG, A.VTWEG, A.MATNR, M.PMATN, K.KBETR, A.DATAB, A.DATBI FROM pdp.KONP AS K
INNER JOIN pdp.A073 AS A ON
    A.KNUMH = K.KNUMH
INNER JOIN pdp.MVKE AS M ON
    M.VKORG = M.VKORG
    AND M.VTWEG = A.VTWEG AND M.MATNR = A.MATNR
      WHERE A.MANDT = '510' 
AND A.VKORG = '1010'
AND A.VTWEG ='D1'
AND GETDATE() < A.DATBI
AND GETDATE() > A.DATAB 
AND M.PMATN = ''
```

Query #2 - parent article number exists in field so join that with article to find the price from the parant:

```
SELECT distinct A.MANDT, A.VKORG, A.VTWEG, A.MATNR, M.PMATN, K.KBETR, A.DATAB, A.DATBI FROM pdp.KONP AS K
INNER JOIN pdp.A073 AS A ON
    A.KNUMH = K.KNUMH
INNER JOIN pdp.MVKE AS M ON
    M.VKORG = M.VKORG
    AND M.VTWEG = A.VTWEG AND M.PMATN = A.MATNR
WHERE A.MANDT = '510' 
AND A.VKORG = '1010'
AND A.VTWEG ='D1'
AND GETDATE() < A.DATBI
AND GETDATE() > A.DATAB
```

Thanks and I hope I made some kind of sense trying to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you would UNION the two queries.  You may want to add a field to both queries, a literal value of some kind as a marker of which query produced the row.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this query, but I assume this should work.

```
SELECT distinct A.MANDT, A.VKORG, A.VTWEG, A.MATNR, M.PMATN, K.KBETR, A.DATAB, A.DATBI FROM pdp.KONP AS K
INNER JOIN pdp.A073 AS A ON
    A.KNUMH = K.KNUMH
INNER JOIN pdp.MVKE AS M ON
    M.VKORG = M.VKORG
    AND M.VTWEG = A.VTWEG AND (((M.PMATN = A.MATNR) AND M.PMATN IS NOT NULL) OR ((M.MATNR = A.MATNR) AND M.PMATN IS NULL))
WHERE A.MANDT = '510' 
AND A.VKORG = '1010'
AND A.VTWEG ='D1'
AND GETDATE() < A.DATBI
AND GETDATE() > A.DATAB
```